# Apache geoip not work: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"

Tags: apache-2.4, geoip

**testgeoip.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>What is my IP address - determine or retrieve my IP address</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) { {
$pipaddress = getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR);
$ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
echo "Your Proxy IP address is : ".$pipaddress. " (via $ipaddress) " ;
} else {
$ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
echo "Your IP address is : $ipaddress";
}
$country = getenv(GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME);
$country_code = getenv(GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE);
echo "<br/>Your country : $country ( $country_code ) ";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Apache/2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pipaddress = getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR);
$ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
```

Quote your strings.

```
$pipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
$ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
```

Comment: The answer makes this a question related to programming rather than server configuration. Voting to migrate this to Stack overflow.